# Windows Firewall service is ON, but Windows SBS Console (security tab) says that it isn't

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

i have problem using SBS server 2008, my server use windows server 2008 and the FIREWALL is automatic ON. but when i check in the SBS Console (security tab) the Server Firewall is OFF (Status Critical)

why this is happen ??
i have try to OFF and then ON the Windows Firewall but when i refresh, still status is Critical

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Went through many posts online, none worked for my issue.

Ended up Restoring Default Policy in the "Advanced Firewall with Advanced Security" and voila.

Although it could have been a multi-step repair, as I had originally deleted the REPOSITORY folder under `windows\system32\wbem`, which didn't fix this issue, BUT did fix an updates reporting issue I was having in the SBS Console.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall service has to be on; and your default action for inbound can't be to allow all (which is probably not the case right now). Open Advanced Firewall Settings MMC and check the settings.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I usually just use netsh
    netsh firewall set opmode mode=disable
This should still work on 2k8sbe or just use ? for help